# Unable to replace fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a collections of fragment as :
[Fragment1][Fragment2][Fragment3]

I'm using ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter. What I'm trying to do is to replace Fragment2 to another fragment (let's call it Fragment4), when a view inside Fragment2 is clicked. I'm using the code as below :

```
newMsgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                swapFragment(new Fragment4());
            }
        });
    private void swapFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Then when I clicked on the newMsgBtn, it detect the click but it's unable to change the fragment. Any idea how to do this ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kingfisher Phuocr [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481520/8164116), you can change the fragment in this method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ArrayList myList = FragmentStatePagerAdapter.customFragmentsArrayList.remove(position);
    myList.add(position,new Fragment_Number());   //i.e. your fragment number
    viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I can't change the view even after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Okay, wait. I', working on it.

Comment: Check out my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be done in your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. You should do something like:

```
new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size(); // the fragments list
}

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
}
}
```

Every time you want to change your viewpager fragment, you can call:

```
fragments.remove(1); //remove your fragment 2
fragments.add(1,fragment4); // add your fragment4 into the 2 position
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: but how do I go back to fragment2 from fragment4 onBackPressed()? Thanks

Comment: I cannot replace the fragment, even after notifying the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix :

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.adapter.fragmentList.remove(0);
    activity.adapter.fragmentTitleList.remove(0);
    activity.adapter.fragmentList.add(0,fragment);
    activity.adapter.fragmentTitleList.add(0,fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    activity.pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Make sure you `adapter` object and `pager` (ViewPager) instance are public.